# What does the header(-type=>'text') print in cgi in Perl

Tags: python, python-3.x, perl, header, cgi

I'm really new to cgi and trying to convert a Perl cgi script to Python.

I came across these statements in the script.

```
my $q = new CGI;
print $q->header(-type=>'text');
```

By looking at it I can understand that q is a scalar variable which possess the form data from which the CGI script is being called.

But what does the print statement above do?

Will it check if the type header's value in form header dictionary and print True or False based on that?

I don't have Perl interpreter to execute and check the output.

Comment: Most systems nowadays have Perl installed or just two clicks away for installing. See http://strawberryperl.com/ for installing Perl on Windows. Please look at the documentation of the CGI module ( https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod ), where your questions can be answered directly.

Comment: CGI programs work by sending HTML through the standard output stream, so that's what the print statement is doing.  It is sending the header.  `q` is a reference to an an object of class `CGI`.

Comment: If you want to convert code from one language to another it generally helps knowing what the code does. Running it is quite helpful for that. You cannot reverse-engineer something without understanding its quirks, and you can't know about them without running it.

Comment: Your question title talks about an `html` content type, but your body talks about `text`. Neither answer has said anything to either of these shortcuts. What is it? Text, HTML or a specific type?

Comment: Can the moderators please find out who voted this down, and take away their voting rights please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Starting the output**

> We use the CGI object to print out the HTTP header
>   for the output:
>
> ```
> print $q->header;
> ```
>
> This gives you the following HTTP header:
>
> ```
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
> ```
>
> If you need to have any extra options in your header, for example you may not want the
>   default 'type', you can just pass them in to the header method:
>
> ```
> print $q->header(-type => "text/plain");
> ```
>
> This gives you the following HTTP header:
>
> ```
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
> ```

For more info visit [here](http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/cgi_script.html).

Comment: So, that means `print $q->header(-type=>'text');` sets the `Content-Type` to `text/plain` and returns `true` or `false` based on the result. Finally print will print **true** or **false**. Am I correct?

Comment: No, that is false, The `header` method returns the string. That's why the string is printed. See the documentation.

Comment: @Sukumar No, as @Corion says `header` method returns a string which in-turn sent through the standard output stream by the print statement.

Comment: Thank you all. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [CGI.pm documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#Creating-a-standard-http-header)

> `header()` returns the `Content-type:` header. You can provide your own MIME type if you choose, otherwise it defaults to `text/html`. An optional second parameter specifies the status code and a human-readable message. For example, you can specify 204, "No response" to create a script that tells the browser to do nothing at all. Note that RFC 2616 expects the human-readable phase to be there as well as the numeric status code.
>
> ```
> print $cgi->header( -Content_length => 3002 );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

"What does it do?"

`my $q = new CGI` creates a new https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI object, which can do a great many things for you. The best things are the params, the path info and the headers.

`print $q->header(-type=>'text')` prints the header, which tells the browser what is being generated. `-type=>'text'` is insufficient; it *should* be a complete MIME type, such as `text/plain`, `text/html`, `text/csv`, `application/json` or a great many others. You can even generate an image and make the type `image/jpeg` or something.

It will also print the status, which would be **200**, for **OK**. Your program *should* work without it, but no harm in adding it.

You're trying to port this to Python, and I don't know what options Python has to write this, but you likely don't need it. Just separate whatever header entries you want to throw in, such as expires tags, with newlines (`\n`), then add another one to separate the header from the body.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous posters said:

`header()` returns the `Content-type: header`. You can provide your own `MIME` type if you choose, otherwise it defaults to `text/html`. An *optional second parameter* specifies the status code and a human-readable message.

For example, you can specify `204`, *"No response"* to create a script that tells the browser to do nothing at all.

See also: https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI

Note that `RFC 2616` expects *the human-readable phase to be there as well as the numeric status code*.